# IntelliJ : How to enable JPAQL validation without persistence.xml?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, intellij-idea, spring-java-config

I configured JPA/Hibernate in Spring using Java config and without any `persistence.xml` file, using the `packagesToScan` property of the `EntityManagerFactory` :

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
    emf.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"ch.gbif.swissBiodivPortal.model.entities"});

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    emf.setJpaProperties(hibernateConfigProperties());

    return emf;
}
```

But now IntelliJ IDEA does not understand it any more, and my entities in JPAQL queries are marked in red with the following message, and auto-completion does not work :

> Can't resolve symbol 'MyEntityName'

Is it possible to configure IntelliJ so it also scans a given package for JPA `@Entity` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out I had not properly configured Spring in the IntelliJ project.

After adding a Spring facet to the module and mapping my two `@Configuration` annotated classes, IntelliJ perfectly recognizes the entities in my JPAQL queries again.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using? I am on 14.1.7 and I have added the Spring facet to my project but still my entities are not recognized.

Comment: It is now working after adding the JPA facet without specifying any descriptors.